# Solve the integral $\int \sin\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: integration

$$\int _0^{+\infty } \sin\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$$
Please, help me with this problem.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is correct? There doesn't appear to be a finite antiderivative.

Comment: Generally you need to prove the convergence of the integral.

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: (After the limits were added:) Okay, that's better. What have you tried?

Comment: Well, to prove the convergence, we need to solve the indefinite integral, which I can't do.

Comment: "Well, to prove the convergence, we need to solve the indefinite integral" No, not at all.

Comment: Hint: change variable to $u = \sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, the end result equals to $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\sin 2+\cos 2\right) \approx 0.6180726066...$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Too long for a comment:** Let $~S(k)~=~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\sin\bigg(x+\dfrac1x\bigg)~\frac{dx}{x^k\sqrt x}~;~$ then $~S(0)=S(1)=$

$=~\sqrt{\dfrac\pi2}~(\cos2+\sin2).~$ Also, for $k>0,~$ we have $~S(k)~=~\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2^k}~(A_k\cos2+B_k\sin2),~$

where the first twenty values of $A_k$ can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6ebh.png), and those of $B_k$ are available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6jo1.png).

A similar expression holds for $~C(k)~=~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\cos\bigg(x+\dfrac1x\bigg)~\frac{dx}{x^k\sqrt x}~=~\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2^k}~(B_k\cos2-$

$-A_k\sin2),~$ for $k>0,~$ and $~C(0)=C(1)=\sqrt{\dfrac\pi2}~(\cos2-\sin2)$.

Comment: And you could not give the book where there are these formulas, please?

Comment: @andre1: I did not take the formulas from any book; I discovered them using *Mathematica*.